# nginx module: capture whole response body

Tags: nginx, filter, module, buffer

Although Nginx is a really interesting piece of software, the lack of documentation is making me crazy.

**Goal:** capture the whole response body, which would be logged on the server.

**Problem:** I have always a single buffer which size is ZERO.

**Approach**

I would expect to be able to accomplish this requirement with a [body filter](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#filters-body), which would "wait" for `last_buf` before iterate the full buffers chain.

```
/**
 * @param   ngx_http_request_t     *r     HTTP request
 * @param   ngx_chain_t            *in    Buffer chain
 */
static ngx_int_t
create_response_snapshot(ngx_http_request_t *r, ngx_chain_t *in)
{
    ngx_chain_t *chain = NULL;
    int chain_contains_last_buffer = 0;
    size_t buffer_size = 0;

    // check if body is complete
    chain = in;
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        if (chain->buf->last_buf)
        {
            chain_contains_last_buffer = 1;
        }

        if (NULL == chain->next)
            break;

        chain = chain->next;
    }

    if (0 == chain_contains_last_buffer)
    {
        // response is not complete
        return ngx_http_next_body_filter(r, in);
    }

    // Response Content-Length
    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ALERT,r->connection->log,0,"Content-Length: %d",
                  r->headers_out.content_length_n);

    // lets iterate buffers chain
    for (chain = in; NULL != chain; chain = chain->next)
    {
        buffer_size = ngx_buf_size(chain->buf);
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ALERT,r->connection->log,0,"buffer_size#%d",buffer_size);
    }

    return ngx_http_next_body_filter(r, in);
}
```

Comment: The lack of documentation is driving me crazy also! The only guide I've found (Evan Miller's) doesn't begin to explain the purpose of most of the `ngx_but_t` members.

I think in this case you need to keep adding the `in` chain to the `busy` member of your module context until you get the last buf. This is because your filter gets called many times, the one containing `last_buf` is the final call, and it is always isolated from what I have seen.

Comment: Oh, and then you would maybe return `NGX_OK` instead of calling `ngx_http_next_body_filter` if you didn't get the final chain. Then pass the entire chain on to the remaining filters as once. You're basically removing Nginx's ability to process the output in chunks, which kind of defeats the point.

Comment: @GVH "I think in this case you need to keep adding the in chain to the busy member of your module context until you get the last buf". Can you explain the "busy member". I have no idea about what it is supposed to be.

About returning "NGX_OK", according to Evan Miler's tutorial, each filter is responsible to call the next filter.

I will dig deeply on other modules.

Answer (score 4):

My comment got too big to be a comment, but I don't feel like it's a proper answer - oh well.

To re-iterate, the problem with the code you've posted is that your module's body filter function won't be called on the whole chain at once. It gets called on the first piece, then the second piece, until the `nth` piece. Finally it gets called on a completely empty chain, for whatever reason the buf with `last_buf = 1` is always by itself and empty.

So I think what you want to do is "dam" the flow of buffers by accumulating them in your module without releasing any to the next filter until you have all of them at once.

Check out the substitution filter module: http://lxr.nginx.org/source//src/http/modules/ngx_http_sub_filter_module.c

It uses a "busy" chain which is what I was referring to. From what I've been able to tell it uses it to keep track of which buffers have actually been sent (when this happens the size gets set to zero) and adds those to the module context's free list for re-use. See ngx_http_sub_output on line 438 for this behavior.

My suggestion was to do something like what that module does, except without calling the next filter until you have the entire page. You can't call next_filter if you want to process the entire page as a whole, since doing that will result in data getting sent to the client. Again this runs counter to Nginx's design, so I think you should find an alternative that doesn't require the whole response body at once if you can.